# Is there any published timeline to the comic book series "Nexus" by Mike Baron and Steve Rude

Tags: comics, nexus

I've been a follower of the [*Nexus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_(comics)) comics since the 1980s and have reread the Omnibus recently. The passage of time is usually expressed in "cycles" (about ten days, IIRC) and sometimes in Earth solar years, but there are many inconsistencies if you compare these casual references to each other and also if you compare them to the growth of the Nexus children.

Is there a guide to the comic that includes a detailed timeline that includes important moments, such as these?

- The beginning of Nexus' occupation of Ylum.
- The arrival to Ylum of Tyrone, Dave and the first refugees.
- The arrival of Sundra
- The birth of Nexus' daughters
- The first elections in Ylum
- The Soviet invasion
- The Merk's deal with the Loomis sisters

Preferably a "word of God" canon, i.e. Mike Baron, but would accept a fan database.

Comment: You could try writing Mike Baron and ask. However, I suspect that the timeline is deliberately kept vague - especially after the fall of the real Soviet Union.